# The session value is not reset

Tags: php

I created a form using html, jquery, css and php.
I defined the session['level'] that each level, the value of session['level'] will be plus one and then include the next page.
But, I bumped into a problem.
if I refresh page the session['level'] value stays and when I click the "new_form" button again its skips levels.
What that I want to do is that if the user refresh the page it will stay in the level he was and not return back to the index.php AND that it will be impossible to skip levels.
How I do it?
I am really appreciate your help. thanks!

```
<?php 
    session_start();
?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--The form is here..-->
    <?php
      if (!array_key_exists('level', $_SESSION)) {
          $_SESSION['level']  = 1;
          if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
              include ('page2.php');    
          } 
      } elseif ($_SESSION['level'] == 1) {
          $_SESSION['level'] = 2;
          if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {    
              include ('page3.php');    
          }
      }elseif ($_SESSION['level'] == 2) {
          $_SESSION['level'] = 3;
          if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {        
              include ('page4.php');
          }
      } elseif ($_SESSION['level'] == 3) {
        $_SESSION['level'] = 4;
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            include ('page5.php');
        }
    }
  ?>

  <footer>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <input type="button" name="new_form" class="btn btn-primary btn-new" onclick="show();" /><br>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-new" />
    </form>
  </div>

  <img src="footer.png">

  </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.2.8/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
  <script> $.validate(); </script>
  <script>
   function show() {
     $('#if-1-1').fadeIn(800);
   }
   </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code just assumes that ANY load of the page is a "go to next page" action. so any refresh moves forward. you need to signal HOW the page load occured and only move forward when the next page is explicitly requested. e.g. `<a href="page.php?page=3>next</a>`, while they're on `page.php?page=2`. if they reload, they just get page 2 again. if they click the link, then they move forward to page 3

Comment: `session_start();    if(!empty($_SESSION['level'])
{
    echo $_SESSION['level'];
} `  ?

Comment: Marc B I want the url to be index.php in all the levels, because of that I use include and not links in the button to next page

Comment: How is your form even submitting? You don't have a submit button. You need to clarify this a lot. Under what circumstance do you want to advance? on the submit that right now cannot even take place?

Comment: developerwjk I have submit buttons In the others pages here I use jquery to hide and show the form in index.php using the button

Comment: `<input type='button'` is not `<input type='submit'` ... did you sneak Ajax in here somewhere or something? If you're using Ajax, why refresh the page at all. Just refresh one small part of it.

Comment: developerwjk This is not the whole code, the whole code is very longer then that, just realize that there is submit buttons.. And I don't using Ajax I am using jquery to SHOW the hidden form in this page

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be that when you refresh the page the `SESSION` value wasn't saved. You can add a hidden field in your form an then reset the level value but remember that hidden field can be hijacked.

```
<?php
    $level = 1;
    if (array_key_exists('level', $_SESSION)) $level = $SESSION['level'];
?>
<input type="hidden" name="level" value="<?php echo $level;?>"/>
```

In your php code forget about the `$SESSION['level']`

```
if (!isset($_POST['level'])) {
        //error
}
else {
    $Savedlevel = $_POST['level'];
    //etc
}
```

**Edit:** I get your point know, the best would be to use the previous solution, you could enconde the level to prevent hijacking, but if you want a fast solution, use this code. Its a ugly patch but it should do the trick.

```
<?php
    if (!array_key_exists('level', $_SESSION)) {
        $_SESSION['level']  = 1;
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
            include ('page2.php');    
        }
    } else{
        if (!isset($_POST) && $SESSION['level'] > 1) {
          $SESSION['level'] = $SESSION['level'] - 1;
        }

        if ($_SESSION['level'] == 1) {
            $_SESSION['level'] = 2;
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {    
                include ('page3.php');    
            }
        }elseif ($_SESSION['level'] == 2) {
            $_SESSION['level'] = 3;
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {        
                include ('page4.php');
            }
        } elseif ($_SESSION['level'] == 3) {
            $_SESSION['level'] = 4;
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                include ('page5.php');
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

But you should do other checks anyway to see if the fields are correct and they should pass the level.

Comment: Thanks first. I used this before but I noticed that as you said It can be hacked and that's why I didn't use hidden input

Comment: I think this answer is a little premature considering he doesn't even have a submit button on the form.

Comment: I understand you rigth know, try the other trick, it could work. If they skip one level then subtract one level to session.